# Check username/password on wordpress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am trying to figure how I can check a user's password which is stored on a sql database on wordpress. I've been searching for this all day, but the solution seems very simple, however I can't get it to work.

Running this code returns a blank page, so I don't know what's going on.
Also entering a wrong user/password, doesn't display an error message.

It seems I have to use wp_signon() as explained here:

But when I run this code on a php file on my bluehost server, the same one that hosts the wordpress site, it doesn't work.

```
<?php

custom_login("joe","joepass");

function custom_login($username, $password) {

$creds = array();
$creds['user_login'] = $username;
$creds['user_password'] = $password;
$creds['remember'] = true;

$user = wp_signon( $creds, false );

if ( is_wp_error($user) )
    echo $user->get_error_message();
}


// run it before the headers and cookies are sent
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'custom_login' );


?>
```

What am I missing here? It's probably something very basic, but I'm completely clueless as to what to do.

My server hosts two websites. So don't I need to specify which database and table it needs to use to validate the user/pass?

If I put an echo statement after '$user = wp_signon( $creds, false );', it doesn't get printed. Why is that? Shouldn't it print the statement, wp_signon returns a $user?

Sorry if the answer is simple and if it has been asked before, could you please point me a solution.

Thanks.

Comment: you need to turn on php errors. If i am reading you correctly you are accessing the php file directly? if so wp does not exist because its not called by your file and hence functions do not exist.

Comment: Yeah, turning on errors shows the issues.
I'm building an app, and want the users to use the same accounts as they created through the website. The passwords are encrypted, and from what I've been reading, decrypting is not an option.

So I will need to encrypt the password entered by the user and compare it to the stored one. Since wp_signon() won't work, in what can I achieve this?

Comment: You need to check out the hashing used by wp https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.3/src/wp-includes/pluggable.php#L0 - search for phpass in this and you fill find the path to this file, you should be able to recreate the hashing function, or call wp_load() in the file if you are lazy :)

Answer (score 1):

The reason you're getting a blank page is because you're triggering a fatal error in PHP.

You've created a function called `custom_login()` which has two required parameters, username and password. Then you hook that function into the `after_setup_theme` action.

```
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'custom_login' );
```

This hook isn't going to pass in any arguments to custom login and since it requires two that's the source of your problem.